# MS SQL 2005 - Increment a number inside a String data

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

In one of my column the value and the sequence stored together. For example

Country= US
Product= Shoe then the item code would be **US000SHOE**

If for the same country and same product exists then that product ID would be **US001SHOE**.

As you can see, each time a product is added for a country we have to increment the number by one. How should i do get the number from a String value and increment it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply have three columns

```
country | an_auto_increment_column | product
```

(in sql-server auto_increment is an identity column)

To get your product code you could build it on the fly

```
SELECT
country + right('000' + an_auto_increment_column, 3) + product AS your_brandnew_ProductID
FROM yourTable
```

When you'd insert into the table you wouldn't even have to care about incrementing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of where the middle three numbers (ONLY) increment, based on using a `SUBSTRING` and `CASE WHEN`:

```
CREATE TABLE ##Values(
    ColumnValue VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO ##Values
VALUES ('US000SHOE')
    , ('US001SHOE')

SELECT *
FROM ##Values

-- This would be when someone adds a new value to the table (in a procedure or direct call):
DECLARE @countrycode VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @product VARCHAR(4)
SET @countrycode = 'US'
SET @product = 'SHOE'

INSERT INTO ##Values
SELECT @countrycode + 
    CASE WHEN LEN(CAST((MAX(SUBSTRING(ColumnValue,3,3)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(3))) = 1 THEN '00' + CAST((MAX(SUBSTRING(ColumnValue,3,3)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(1))
        WHEN LEN(CAST((MAX(SUBSTRING(ColumnValue,3,3)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(3))) = 2 THEN '0' + CAST((MAX(SUBSTRING(ColumnValue,3,3)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(2))
        ELSE CAST((MAX(SUBSTRING(ColumnValue,3,3)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(3)) END
    + @product
FROM ##Values

SELECT *
FROM ##Values

DROP TABLE ##Values
```

The `CASE WHEN` will allow you to begin your codes with 000 when you want, otherwise `TSQL` will think that adding 000 + 1 = 1 (which is mathematically true, but not the way you want your values to appear).  This also assumes that your country codes are only two `VARCHARS`; if they may be anywhere from 2 to 5, the `SUBSTRING` in the above example won't work, in which case you'd be better breaking everything into pieces on a staging table, then doing a final insert with everything added (or some table between the beginning and ending).

Answer (score 0):

Create the following function to extract the number from the string in question

```
create function [dbo].[GetNumbersFromText](@String varchar(2000))
returns table as return
(

  with C as

  (

    select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as int) as Number,

           stuff(s.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '') as Value

    from (select @String+' ') as S(Value)

      cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)

      cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)

    union all

    select cast(substring(S.Value, S1.Pos, S2.L) as int),
           stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos + S2.L, '')

    from C as S

      cross apply (select patindex('%[0-9]%', S.Value)) as S1(Pos)

      cross apply (select patindex('%[^0-9]%', stuff(S.Value, 1, S1.Pos, ''))) as S2(L)

    where patindex('%[0-9]%', S.Value) > 0

  )

  select Number

  from C

)
```

And the following code will use the function extrat the number, add 1 and reformat it with 3 digit

```
DECLARE @S varchar(max)
set @S = 'US000SHOE'
DECLARE @countrycode VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @product VARCHAR(4)
SET @countrycode = 'US'
SET @product = 'SHOE'

SELECT @countrycode + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,number+1),3) + @product FROM GetNumbersFromText(@S) option (maxrecursion 0)
```